# Write log to a file using Sipp

Tags: voip, asterisk, freeswitch

How could write log to a file using Sipp, and How could I know every call return status,

I only want to kown every call return response status, for example 200 ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run sipp and see params:

```
-trace_msg       : Displays sent and received SIP messages in <scenario file
                  name>_<pid>_messages.log

-trace_shortmsg  : Displays sent and received SIP messages as CSV in
                  <scenario file name>_<pid>_shortmessages.log
```

Comment: Also, a great way to say "thank you" (if the solution is indeed a solution, like this) is to mark the question as answered @user1369887